# How do you inject dependencies in a class, that depends on a class, which depends on another class in C++?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection

I'm trying to implement dependency injection in a C++ project. However, due to the structure of the dependencies, I'm getting a segmentation fault which I can't solve.

As an example I constructed the following classes and interfaces. I have a class called MyClass which has a dependency on Dependency. Dependency has a dependency on OtherDependency. To allow for proper testing, I inherit the dependencies from an interface, i.e. IDependency and IOtherDependency. OtherDependency has a function some_function().

In main.cpp I create an instance of MyClass and then try to call some_function(). Unfortunately, this gives a segmentation fault:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

MyClass.h:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include "IDependency.h"

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(IDependency *dependency);
    ~MyClass();

    IDependency *_dependency = nullptr;
};

#endif
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

#include <iostream>

MyClass::MyClass(IDependency *dependency) : _dependency(dependency) {}

MyClass::~MyClass() {}
```

Dependency.h:

```
#ifndef DEPENDENCY_H
#define DEPENDENCY_H

#include "IDependency.h"
#include "IOtherDependency.h"

class Dependency : public IDependency
{
public:
    Dependency(IOtherDependency *other_dependency);
    ~Dependency();

    IOtherDependency *_other_dependency = nullptr;
};

#endif
```

Dependency.cpp:

```
#include "Dependency.h"

#include <iostream>

Dependency::Dependency(IOtherDependency *other_dependency) : _other_dependency(other_dependency) {}

Dependency::~Dependency() {}
```

IDependency.h:

```
#ifndef IDEPENDENCY_H
#define IDEPENDENCY_H

#include "IOtherDependency.h"

class IDependency
{
public:
    IOtherDependency *_other_dependency;
};

#endif
```

OtherDependency.h:

```
#ifndef OTHERDEPENDENCY_H
#define OTHERDEPENDENCY_H

#include "IOtherDependency.h"

class OtherDependency : public IOtherDependency
{
public:
    OtherDependency();
    ~OtherDependency();

    void some_function();
};

#endif
```

OtherDependency.cpp:

```
#include "OtherDependency.h"

#include <iostream>

OtherDependency::OtherDependency() {}

OtherDependency::~OtherDependency() {}

void OtherDependency::some_function()
{
    std::cout << "I am OtherDependency." << std::endl;
}
```

IOtherDependency.h:

```
#ifndef IOTHERDEPENDENCY_H
#define IOTHERDEPENDENCY_H

class IOtherDependency
{
public:
    virtual void some_function() = 0;
};

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    OtherDependency *other_dependency = new OtherDependency;
    Dependency *dependency = new Dependency(other_dependency);
    MyClass my_class(dependency);

    my_class._dependency->_other_dependency->some_function();
}
```

What am I doing wrong / do I need to change?

Answer (score 2):

You have two variables called `_other_dependency`: one in `IDependency`, the other in `Dependency`.  The `Dependency` constructor initialized the latter, while the one in the `IDependency` class retains its default nullptr value.

When you access `my_class._dependency->_other_dependency`, the `other_dependency` will be the one in `IDependency`, because `_dependency` points to the base class.

One way to fix this is to remove the `other_dependency` from `Dependency`, and pass the value from the `Dependency` constructor to `IDependency` to properly initialize its member.